# Error Interface not found only on develop server

Tags: laravel, classloader, laravel-nova

I have an application with `laravel nova`.

This is my folder structure

```
app
 |_Nova
  |_Actions
    |_Messsage
     |_BroadcastMessage.php
     |_Message.php
     |_ZMessage.php
```

File `Message.php`:

```php
namespace App\Nova\Actions\Message;

interface Message { ... }
```

File `BroadcastMessage.php`:

```php
namespace App\Nova\Actions\Message;

class BroadcastMessage implements Message { ... }
```

File `ZMessage.php`:

```php
namespace App\Nova\Actions\Message;

class ZMessage implements Message { ... }
```

I has a typo error in folder `Messsage` name (it has an extra `s` character), so it is same with namespace declared , but It work normally in my local environment. When code is uploaded to developing environment, it display error `Interface 'App\Nova\Actions\Message\Message' not found`.

I do not understand in this case, why this error only occur in developing environment?

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `s` on your `Messsage` folder.

Comment: I know, I've described it in my post. My question is why error only occur in develop evironment